# Exclude a single li a when it is clicked on

Tags: jquery

I have a responsive menu where I need to exclude a single li a when it is clicked on.

Basicly the jQuery are changing the active element when the menu are clicked on but when the screen is resized to a smaller size the menu is hidden behind the 3 line icon.

I do not want the 3 line icon to aquire the active status.
How is this done ???

My HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="menu" id="myTopnav">
        <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li class="icon">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size: 0.9375em;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("ul.menu li a").click(function () {
        $("ul.menu li a").not(this).removeClass("active");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter out the li with the `icon` class inside the selector:   `$("ul.menu li:not(.icon) a")`

Also, as a sidenote, you can buffer the listitems to prevent the need of a second query:

```
var lis = $("ul.menu li:not(.icon) a").click(function () {
        lis.not(this).removeClass("active");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5wmchqun/)

Comment: Worked perfect!!!
Thank you.

The sidenote is nice. Don't know if it makes the script faster though.

Comment: Glad it helps :) The performance gain of the buffered items might be negligible, but often it also helps in maintainability to have the selector only once, in case it has to change in a future adaptation. Might not matter much, but it's the small things in life... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul.menu li a").not("li.icon").click(function () {
```

http://api.jquery.com/not/

Comment: Please give a little bit of context. Code-only or link-only answers are not of high quality.

Comment: I could get the code to work.
The answer above this and below worked as I wanted.

I actually tried something similar before I wrote the question.

Comment: There should have been a "not" in the above comment.
Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the anchor's parent have the class `icon`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("ul.menu li a").click(function () {
        if(!$(this).closest('li').hasClass('icon')){
        $("ul.menu li a").not(this).removeClass("active");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: Worked perfect!
A bit more advanced than the answers above though.
Thank you.

Comment: @FlemmingLemche you can at least upvote both these answers

Comment: Sure no problem, but because I have less than 15 in reputation the system wont change even though I upvote your answer.
Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something as simple as using `:not(.icon)` like so

```
$("ul.menu li:not(.icon) a").click(function () {
    $("ul.menu li a").not(this).removeClass("active");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

let me know if it helps